# what is the meaning of weak in this sentence and is it a verb in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, word-meaning

I found in the book that I'm reading, the use of the word weak. But as weak is put after a noun, then it's not an adjective. So I don't get its meaning.

Quotations:

> "How did you first day go, dear?" the receptionist asked maternally.
>   "Fine", I lied, my voice **weak**. She didn't look convinced.

Comment: Yes, it is an adjective there.  "He came in from the rain, his shoes *soggy*".  *my voice weak* and *his shoes soggy* are so-called "absolute" phrases. These phrases do not contain a tensed verb; they supply information that pertains to the main clause.

Comment: Temba, his arms wide...

Comment: It is an adjective. "My voice weak" is best analysed as a verbless clause functioning as a supplement. It's the verbless analogue of the non-finite supplement "my voice being weak".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A strong voice is loud, easy to hear. A weak voice is quiet and may tremble.

Comment: How does your answer address the OP's concern?

Answer (score 5):

In English, an adjective can appear after a noun, but it has a different nuance -- more *stylized, poetic, or dramatic* -- from the more typical placement.

Standard:

> I walked through the woods alone filled with **dark thoughts** and with a **heavy heart**.

Poetic:

> I walked through the woods alone, my **thoughts dark** and my **heart heavy**.

A "weak voice" is one which is quiet or uncertain, and which possibly stutters or falters in a way that suggests fear, doubt, or insincerity.

As Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions in his comment, these kind of expressions are called "absolute phrases" and don't always contain a verb, but do contain information relevant to the overall sentence.  BillJ (see comment below) classifies it as "a verbless clause functioning as a supplement".  It can be changed to a finite clause by adding the "to be" verb:

> **My voice was weak** as I replied to the secretary.  "Fine," I lied.

Comment: Imho it would be even *more* "poetic, stylised" to dispense with determiners *(**a** heavy heart, **my** heart heavy)* altogether: *I walked through the woods alone, **thoughts dark and heart heavy.*** In which context it only really works with the adjectives *after* their relevant noun referents.

Comment: It is an adjective, but I'd analyse "my voice weak" as a verbless clause functioning as a supplement, where the NP "my voice" is subject of the clause. A finite clause can be reconstructed by adding "was": "my voice was weak".